# Two graph - same page? (R/LaTeX)

Tags: graphics, pdf, pdfpages, r

I am using R to create my graph, and I am doing a paper, where I have to put two graph, as showed in the image:

[image]

In R, my output looks like:

```
y1 <- c(6524, 6701, 6946, 7080, 6920, 6887, 6660, 6746)
y2 <- c(5884, 5749, 6033, 5805, 5643, 5242, 4720, 4324)
x <- c(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8)
pdf(file="graph1.pdf",  title="Some", pointsize=7, width=5, height=4, paper="special")
plot(x,y1,type="l",lty="dotted", col="black", ylim = c(4000,7500))
par(new=TRUE)
plot(x,y2,type="l", lty="solid", col="black", ylim = c(4000,7500)) 
dev.off()

y1 <- c(403, 407, 435, 452, 448, 466, 476, 507)
y2 <- c(844, 934, 950, 1111, 1020, 1058, 1026, 1044)
x <- c(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8)
pdf(file="graph2.pdf",  title="Some", pointsize=7, width=5, height=4, paper="special")
plot(x,y1,type="l",lty="dotted", col="black", ylim = c(400,1200))
par(new=TRUE)
plot(x,y2,type="l", lty="solid", col="black", ylim = c(400,1200))
dev.off()
```

In LaTeX I am using \usepackage{pdfpages} and writing:

```
\begin{figure}[H]
\centering
\caption{Graph1 and Graph2}
\includepdf[pages=-, scale=0.3]{graph1.pdf}
\includepdf[pages=-, scale=0.3]{graph2.pdf}
\end{figure}
```

If someone could help me by doing this in R or LaTeX, I would be very happy.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use `subfigure` !

How about this code :

```
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{subcaption}

\begin{figure}
        \centering
        \begin{subfigure}[b]{0.5\textwidth}
                \includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{pic1}
        \end{subfigure}
        \begin{subfigure}[b]{0.5\textwidth}
                \includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{pic2}
        \end{subfigure}
        \caption{two pictures side by side}
\end{figure}
```

Comment: I do not have .png, but .pdf? Is this possible?

Comment: why don't you simply convert your pdf to png ?

Comment: or give it a try with pdf :-)

Comment: Well, I can place them in. Thanks. But how do I allow the .pdf-files to be wider than the margins? For example: I write 0.5\textwidth my figures want stand side by side, but if I write 0.49\textwidts they will. How do I solve the problem?

Comment: The reason why I am using .pdf is because it looks prettier - in my opinion.

Comment: use `scale=.49` in the place of `0.5\textwidth`, can you share a screenshot to show how prettier it is ?